# Internal CSS is not working for me

Tags: css, html

I inserted this into my html code and it works for ordered list and h1 but it does not work for p.
This is a beginners html i know but usually css for p works but now i don't know why it won't load

```css
h1 {
   color: yellow;
}
p {
   color: green;
   text-decoration: underline;
}
ol {
   list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>My Profile Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <ul>
        <li><strong>Home</strong></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
      </ul>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <h1><center>WELCOME TO HOME PAGE</center></h1>
      <p><center>Choose a page from the menu</p>
      <ol>
        <li><a href="/about.html" list-style-type="none"><img src="forest.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
        <li><a href="/about.html"><img src="forest.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
        <li><a href="/about.html"><img src="forest.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
      </ol>
    </body>
    
  </html>
```

Comment: Can you also add the html part? And what exactly is not working in the `p` part?

Comment: Css works for me, please add your html

Comment: Did you insert it into the head?

Comment: It might just get overwritten by a rule with higher specificity … easiest way to find out are your browser dev tools. With what you have shown here so far however, there is no way for us to tell what it actually is. Please go read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Learn to use an [HTML validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `<center>` from `<p>`
and add `text-align: center;` to css of `<p>`

```css
h1 {
   color: yellow;
}
p {
   color: green;
   text-decoration: underline;
   text-align: center;

}
ol {
   list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>My Profile Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <ul>
        <li><strong>Home</strong></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
      </ul>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <h1><center>WELCOME TO HOME PAGE</center></h1>
      <p>Choose a page from the menu</p>
      <ol>
        <li><a href="/about.html" list-style-type="none"><img src="forest.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
        <li><a href="/about.html"><img src="forest.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
        <li><a href="/about.html"><img src="forest.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
      </ol>
    </body>
    
  </html>
```